ValueError when loading sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier pickle in Python 3.10
I'm encountering an issue while transitioning from Python 3.7.3 to Python 3.10 due to the deprecation of the older version. The problem arises when attempting to load a pickled sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier model.
Environment:
Original: Python 3.7.3, scikit-learn 0.23.1
Current: Python 3.10, scikit-learn 1.3.2
Problem:
When loading the pickled model, I receive the following error:
ValueError: node array from the pickle has an incompatible dtype:
- expected: {'names': ['left_child', 'right_child', 'feature', 'threshold', 'impurity', 'n_node_samples', 'weighted_n_node_samples', 'missing_go_to_left'], 'formats': ['<i8', '<i8', '<i8', '<f8', '<f8', '<i8', '<f8', 'u1'], 'offsets': [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56], 'itemsize': 64}
- got : [('left_child', '<i8'), ('right_child', '<i8'), ('feature', '<i8'), ('threshold', '<f8'), ('impurity', '<f8'), ('n_node_samples', '<i8'), ('weighted_n_node_samples', '<f8')]

Code:
import pickle

for m in models:
    file = 'finalized_model_' + m + '.sav'
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(file, 'rb'))
    df[m] = loaded_model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
    print(m)

Attempted Solution:
I've tried to mitigate this issue by loading and re-saving the model using a higher protocol:
import pickle
from sklearn import model_selection

# Load the model
with open("path_to_old_model.pkl", 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)

# Re-save using a higher protocol
with open("path_to_updated_model.pkl", 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

However, after upgrading the environment to Python 3.10 and the latest version of scikit-learn, I still encounter the same error when attempting to load the re-saved model.
Is there a way to successfully load these models in the newer Python environment without losing their functionality?

From here:

in general, cross-version pickled models aren't supported.

You will not be able to open your pickled model with a newer version of sklearn. You can:

retrain the model with the newer version of sklearn and pickle the parameters. You need to have access to the code and data that was used for training tho.
Maybe open the pickled parameters with scikit-learn 0.23.1 and export it with a different format like ONNX, might work. See here.
Lower your python to 3.8 to be able to use scikit-learn 0.23.1, while still upgrading python version.

